# Running UF-B cable in PVC conduit along house exterior 6/3 for 100'

Tags: wiring

Can I run 100' of UF-B 6/3 cable alongside house exterior in 1" PVC conduit? This is a run from the main breaker inside the house and outside along the restricted access side of the house in 1" S40 PVC, then back inside the house to a dedicated spa breaker sub-panel. 240v 50amp at both breakers for a Spa that draws 31 Amps. Alternatively, I would like to run four 8 AWG individual wires (blk, red, wht, grn) in the same 1" S40 PVC that can handle 9 wires of fill-rate. Is either solution OK, or is there a preference? The run along side the house is gated, cement floored and locked, extremely unlikely to be disturbed or damaged in any way.

Comment: Schedule 40 or 80?  And what circuit is this cable used for?

Comment: Is this conduit running in a place where it could get run into (say by stray lawn equipment)?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for a spa you have no choice but to use individual insulated conductors in conduit since code requires it (with few exceptions).

If it is exposed and above ground most inspectors would require Sch80, unless as you imply it is totally out of harms way.